# Binding MenuItem Visibility to Visibility of the preceding MenuItem

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I want to bind mnuAddLessonAfter's visibility to that of mnuAddLessonBefore. I can't seem to make it work, ie setting mnuAddLessonBefore's visibility to collapsed only hides mnuAddLessonBefore, not mnuAddLessonAfter. What am I doing wrong?

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Name="treeViewLesson"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          SelectedItemChanged="treeViewLesson_SelectedItemChanged"
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="treeViewLesson_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
          AllowDrop="True"
          Drop="treeViewLesson_Drop"
          MouseMove="treeViewLesson_MouseMove"
          DragEnter="treeViewLesson_DragEnter">

<TreeView.ContextMenu>

  <ContextMenu Name="context_menu_lesson">

    <MenuItem Name="mnuAddLesson"
              Header="Add lesson"
              Click="mnuAddLesson_Click" />

    <MenuItem Name="mnuAddLessonBefore"
              Header="Add lesson before"
              Click="mnuAddLessonBefore_Click" />

    <MenuItem Name="mnuAddLessonAfter"
              Header="Add lesson after"
              Click="mnuAddLessonAfter_Click"
              Visibility="{Binding ElementName=mnuAddLessonBefore, Path=Visibility}" />
```

EDIT:

I noticed this in the Output console:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot
>   find source for binding with reference
>   'ElementName=mnuAddLessonBefore'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Visibility;
>   DataItem=null; target element is
>   'MenuItem' (Name='mnuAddLessonAfter');
>   target property is 'Visibility' (type
>   'Visibility')

Comment: This should work, I don't see anything wrong. How are you setting `mnuAddLessonBefore` visibility to collapsed, in the codebehind in `mnuAddLessonBefore_Click`?

Comment: mnuAddLessonBefore's visibility is being set in treeViewLesson_MouseRightButtonDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context menus are tricky to bind against. They exist outside the visual tree of your control, hence they can't find your element name.

Try This workaround

```
 public Window1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    NameScope.SetNameScope(context_menu_lesson, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
  }
```

Comment: Great, thanks, with the NameScope.SetNameSpace(... in the form's constructor, the binding works.